# I Want Remove Continuous collision detection in Box2D at some specific stage how can i over come?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

==> I am  developing game like carom  board Where  i am facing few   issue due to continuous collision detection.

1. As shown in the image due to collision detection striker hanging around with  gray puck and game   can not get continue after that and playing sound continuously over there
2. and i want play sound only first time when striker or puck  hit each other or frame (wall ) but in my case if i put striker near wall sound is playing continuously

[image: Screen Shot] 
Thank you very much in advance
Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I thing you could create a boolean variable that will keep track for collision between two bodies  

    BOOL isCollided;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my view best way would be to maintain some minimum distance between both the sprites after collision detection this should be done in update function. This will resolve your first problem. For second problem just check frame of both the sprites and try to decrease the frame size.